# Bash: How to decode and encode specific URL characters?

Tags: bash, url, awk, decode, encode

This awk command works well for decoding all characters at once:

`awk -niord '{printf RT?$0chr("0x"substr(RT,2)):$0}' RS=%..`

But I need commands to decode and encode specific URL characters.  For example I only need to decode `%3d` and `%26` or vice versa encode `=` and `&` in a file.

`https%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dstackoverflow%26param%3dvalue`

**Desired output for decoding**

`https%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com%2fsearch%3fq=stackoverflow&param=value`

**Desired output for encoding**

`https://google.com/search?q%3dstackoverflow%26param%3dvalue`

**UPDATE**

Although it is possible to use `sed 's/%3d/\=/g' | sed 's/%26/\&/g'` to replace a character, but I'm still looking for a way to decode or encode some specific characters at once, (put them in one sed or awk or whatever instead of using two sed command). Tools other than sed are welcome.

I need to replace `%3d` with `=` and replace `%26` with `&` and vice versa.

*Thanks*

Comment: Try sed, replace these sequences into needed symbols.

Comment: I didn't think about sed :)) Thank you!

Comment: @sof31, could you please post which symbol should be replaced with which value? That will clarify it more, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated the post. Please read ```UPDATE```.

Comment: @sof31, try to combine them like this `sed 's/%3d/\=/g;s/%26/\&/g' file` and please check how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It goes well. Thanks!